# ¿Se pueden hacer operaciones con store local en EXTJS?

Tags: java, array, extjs

tengo un store local en EXTJS que al parecer es un array pero quisiera saber si se pueden hacer operaciones  típicas de array (push,pop....) .

Anexo mi store local .

```
griddetalle.hora3 = new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
            fields: [
                'id',
                'horas3'
            ],
            data: [
              [1, '06:00:00'], [2, '06:30:00'],
                [3, '07:00:00'], [4, '07:30:00'], [5, '08:00:00'], [6, '08:30:00'], [7, '09:00:00'], [8, '09:30:00'], [9, '10:00:00'],
                [10, '10:30:00'], [11, '11:00:00'], [12, '11:30:00'], [13, '12:00:00'], [14, '12:30:00'], [15, '13:00:00'], [16, '13:30:00'],
                [17, '14:00:00'], [18, '14:30:00'], [19, '15:00:00'], [20, '15:30:00'], [21, '16:00:00'], [22, '16:30:00'], [23, '17:00:00'],
                [24, '17:30:00'], [25, '18:00:00'], [26, '18:30:00'], [27, '19:00:00'], [28, '19:30:00'], [29, '20:00:00'], [30, '20:30:00'],
                [31, '21:00:00'], [32, '21:30:00'], [33, '22:00:00'], [34, '22:30:00'], [35, '23:00:00'], [36, '23:30:30'] , [37, '00:00:00'], 
                [38, '00:30:00'], [39, '01:00:00'], [40, '01:30:00'], [41, '02:00:00'], [42, '02:30:00'], [43, '03:00:00'],
                [44, '03:30:00'], [45, '04:00:00'], [46, '04:30:00'], [47, '05:00:00'], [48, '05:30:00']
        ]
        });
```